# Oracle Fractional Date Constraints Meaning

Tags: oracle, where-clause, scheduling, materialized-views

I have a `MY_VIEW_A` which is a union of `MY_VIEW_B` and `MY_MATERIALIZED_VIEW_C`.

`MY_VIEW_B` has a constraint of `MY_DATE  > (SYSDATE - 1) + 1 / 24`.

`MY_MATERIALIZED_VIEW_C` is updated by a job whose interval is `TRUNC(SYSDATE+1) + 1/24`. Note this might be invalid...the issue I am working on is that the job stopped running. Perhaps due to a 10G 11G migration.

I am wonder what the `1/24` means in these situations. From looking around, I believe it is indicating 1 hour. So then I think the following might be what is going on.

1. `MY_VIEW_B` only retrieves entities that have a `MY_DATE` that is in the last 23 hours.
2. `MY_MATERIALIZE_VIEW_C` is updated every 25 hours.

However, this seems to be a problematic scenario. As an entity  made 24 hours ago might not be in either view.

Am I not understanding something? Or is the setup indeed faulty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1/24` does indeed convert to 1 hour in this context.  Personally, I prefer using interval notation rather than adding and removing fractional days.

```
SYSDATE - interval '23' hour
```

seems much more readable to me.

Your materialized view is updated every 24 hours.  It will be updated every day at 1am.

```
TRUNC(SYSDATE+1) + 1/24
```

returns tomorrow at 1am.  `trunc(sysdate)` is midnight today, `trunc(sysdate+1)` is midnight tomorrow, and `trunc(sysdate+1) + 1/24` is tomorrow at 1am.

If you are querying the view between midnight and whenever the materialized view finishes refreshing (presumably some time after 1am), there may be rows that are more than 23 hours old that are not yet reflected in the materialized view. Depending on the architecture (and the reason that entries apparently exist in two different objects), I'd be more concerned about duplicate rows.  At 8am, for example, the materialized view will have data that is only 7 hours old (presumably), which could also be returned from `my_view_b` (I assume that when you say "constraint" you really mean that there is a predicate on `my_view_b` like `WHERE MY_DATE > (SYSDATE - 1) + 1 / 24`).

Taking a step back, though, the approach seems dubious to me.  Having detail level data in a materialized view and in a separate table that is accessed via a view and then going to the expense of doing a `UNION` to remove duplicates seems highly dubious to me.  Materialized views will often improve performance if you are using them to pre-aggregate data or at least to pre-compute something that is costly to compute at runtime.  That doesn't appear to be what you're using them for, though, so I'm rather dubious that this is doing anything other than causing you to use more disk space, put more pressure on the buffer cache, and suffer worse performance.

Comment: Ah, I guess I was thinking interval as in "set the interval of time between runs" instead of "set the interval until the next run". I understand the materialized view now. Was I correct in my understanding of the normal view? (the last 23 hours)

Comment: @RachelG. - Yes.  `(sysdate-1) + 1/24` is 23 hours ago.  I'd prefer to write that as `sysdate - interval '23' hour` since that tends to be harder to misread/ misinterpret.

Comment: As an FYI, the view query returns a lot of results, so the materialized view was meant to hold the old ones while the normal view holds the newest ones. I think unions take care of duplicates correct? As mentioned, `MY_VIEW_A` does a union of the other 2 and that is what is actually queries by the app.

Comment: @RachelG. - A `UNION` "takes care of" duplicates by sorting the entire result so it's not particularly efficient particularly when you're dealing with a relatively large number of results.  I don't understand why putting detail-level data in two physical structures (a materialized view and the table behind the view) and then doing a `UNION` to remove a bunch of duplicates would possibly lead to improved performance.

Comment: It seems a valid solution might be to update the job to use `TRUNC(SYSDATE+1)` (run at midnight tomorrow morning) and the where clause to `MY_DATE > TRUNC(SYSDATE)` (things since midnight). Does that sound legit?

Comment: @RachelG. - It sounds "legit" in that it eliminates the midnight to 1am hole and probably causes a bit less work to remove the duplicates.  I'm still dubious about the general approach, though.  Potentially, though, you'd still miss some data if a row can get committed after midnight with a `my_date` value some time yesterday (i.e. a transaction starts at 11:59pm when `my_date` is assigned and then commits at 12:01am).

Comment: I assumed they wrote it that way because the materialized view query took a long time and they didn't want to run it every time the app needed the info.

Comment: I am honestly not a DBA or anywhere near it. Materialized views are something I first heard about today. LOL

Comment: Well, the materialized view's query only took 569 ms to run. So who knows why they did what they did.